# I'm using adminJS with Postgres & AdminJSExpress.buildAuthenticatedRouter data isn't saved into the database rather it's saved & read in session

Tags: postgresql, adminjs

I'm using adminJS with Postgres & AdminJSExpress.buildAuthenticatedRouter
The problem is that the resource data is not reading from the database tables, rather it's reading from session records. Also the save is saving into session

```
import AdminJS from 'adminjs'
import AdminJSExpress from '@adminjs/express'
import express from 'express'
import Connect from 'connect-pg-simple'
import session from 'express-session'

import { Adapter, Resource, Database } from '@adminjs/sql'




const PORT = 3000
const DEFAULT_ADMIN = {email: 'email',password: 'password',}
AdminJS.registerAdapter({Database,Resource,Adapter})



const authenticate = async (email, password) => {
  if (email === DEFAULT_ADMIN.email && password === DEFAULT_ADMIN.password) {return Promise.resolve(DEFAULT_ADMIN)}
  return null
}

const start = async () => {
  const app = express()
  
  const db = await new Adapter('postgresql', {
    connectionString: 'postgres://user:pwd@localhist:5432/',
    database: 'myDB',
  }).init();
  
  const admin = new AdminJS({
    resources: [
      {resource: db.table('user'), options: {id: 'Users',},},
      {resource: db.table('admin'),
                options: {
                  id: 'Admins',  
                  properties: {
                    id: { isVisible: { list: true, filter: false, show: true, edit: false } },
                    email: { isVisible: { list: true, filter: true, show: true, edit: true } },
                    firstName: { isVisible: { list: true, filter: true, show: true, edit: true } },
                    lastName: { isVisible: { list: true, filter: true, show: true, edit: true } },
                    password: { isVisible: { list: false, filter: false, show: false, edit: false } },
                    photoUrl: { isVisible: { list: true, filter: false, show: true, edit: false } },
                    lastLoginDate: { isVisible: { list: true, filter: false, show: false, edit: false } },
                  },
              },
    },
    ],
  })
  admin.watch()

 
  const ConnectSession = Connect(session)
  const sessionStore = new ConnectSession({
    conObject: {
      connectionString: 'postgres://user:pwd@localhist:5432/myDB',
      ssl: process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production',
    },
    tableName: 'session',
    createTableIfMissing: true,
  })

  const adminRouter = AdminJSExpress.buildAuthenticatedRouter(
    admin,
    {
      authenticate,
      cookieName: 'cookieName',
      cookiePassword: 'secret',
    },
    null,
    {
      store: sessionStore,
      resave: true,
      saveUninitialized: true,
      secret: 'secret',
      cookie: {
        httpOnly: process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production',
        secure: process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production',
      },
      name: 'adminjs',
    }
  )
  app.use(admin.options.rootPath, adminRouter)

  app.listen(PORT, () => {
    console.log(`AdminJS started on http://localhost:${PORT}${admin.options.rootPath}`)
  })
}

start()`
```

Expecting data to be saved in database tables rather than session table